# Cationic Detergent with no odor

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, everyday-chemistry, aqueous-solution, biochemistry

I am looking for a cationic detergent for a project.  Unfortunately most ( or all?) cationic detergents are quaternary ammonium that smell like rotten fish or even worse 
The product I am working on can not have odor. Is there such cationic detergent out there or an odor neutralizer ?

Comment: _sigh_ I guess you didn't check your misunderstanding in practice. These are quaternary *ammonium salts* and only neutral amines not their salts may have bad smell.

Comment: @Mithoron thank you. That is a good point.  What I am looking for is something with foaming capacity and not just disinfectant like most of them. If you know any QA salt that can make foam and bubbles ( like soap ) that would be the answer and I highly appreciate that.

Comment: Also you are right , edited the question to fix ammonium